# Pine script - Calculate indicator of changing length

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to calculate a simple moving average with changing length (starting from a specific point each bar adds 1 to the indicator calculation length) so that at the moment of bar0 the indicator length is 1, at bar1 the length is 2, etc.

I don't necessarily need to see it on the chart but I can't think of another way I can make sure the calculation is correct.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

src = close
a = sma(src, 5)
cal = barssince(a > 29000)
len = cal == 0 ? 1 : cal // there shouldn't be any 0 values from the above function but just to make sure.

plot(len) // works
b = sma(src, len) // this line also works (at least there are no errors) but plotting it on the chart doesn't work
plot(b)
```

The error (I can't post pictures yet):
Study Error
Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the "sma" function. It must be > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calculating the sma from bar to bar once the starting condition is met you avoid the "Pine cannot determine the referencing length of the series" error which you would have run into next.

```
src = input(close)
var bool started = false
var int n = 1
var float b = na

a = sma(src, 5)

if started == false and a > 29000
    started := true
    b := src
else if started == true
    n += 1
    b := ((b * (n - 1)) + src) / n

plot(b)
```